# Create a row using if and vlookup functions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Below is the result from EXCEL and I wish to have in SQL:

```
A   | B    |   C |   D
oid |rate  |from |  ori_rate
1   | a    |     |  a
2   | b    | 1   |  a
3   | c    | 2   |  a
4   | d    | 3   |  a
5   | e    | 4   |  a
6   | f    | 5   |  a
7   | g    | 6   |  a
8   | h    | 7   |  a
9   | i    | 8   |  a
10  | j    | 9   |  a
11  | k    |     |  k
12  | iii  | 11  |  k
13  | l    | 12  |  k
14  | m    | 5   |  a
15  | h    | 6   |  a
```

The **ori_rate** formula using Excel is **=IF(C2="",B2,VLOOKUP(C2,A:D,4,0))**, how can I convert this formula to be apply into MySQL and create a new column--**ori_rate** beside oid,rate and from.

For the row1 `1    a               a`, it means the oid='1' have the rate='a' and it is the source. For row2 `2   b          1    a`, it means oid='2', and have the rate='b', and it is source from oid='1', so the purpose of my formula is to get the ori_rate=source's rate which is 'a'.

The table I have in MySQL is as below:

```
A   | B    |   C 
oid |rate  |from
1   | a    |      
2   | b    | 1      
3   | c    | 2      
4   | d    | 3      
5   | e    | 4      
6   | f    | 5      
7   | g    | 6      
8   | h    | 7      
9   | i    | 8   
10  | j    | 9    
11  | k    |      
12  | iii  | 11   
13  | l    | 12   
14  | m    | 5    
15  | h    | 6
```

Which I have is the oid, rate and from.

Comment: What's the logic behind your Excel formula? Try to type it out instead of posting the formula

Comment: I really don't understant the question, what is your table in mysql ?